# I don't know why my external CSS file is not working with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a issue regarding loading external CSS file in my **index.php** I have put the external CSS file in the end of all other CSS files like **bootstrap** and **font awesome** etc but when I am changing some design by external CSS file's code its not working because I think it's not loading in my web page.

Here is my code of **index.php** file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
   <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
   
   <div>
       
   </div>
   
   <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
   
   <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

This is coding of **header.php** file

```html
<header class="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">O.S.P</a>--> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
            <img src="img/osp_logo_1.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px";>
        </a>
        <span class="navbar-text">Online Service Provider</span>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active mr-sm-5"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-sm-5">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="services.php" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Services Type 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Services Type 2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-sm-5"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-sm-5"><a class="nav-link" href="sign-in.php">Sign In</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="sign-up.php">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline" action="">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and this is my external CSS file's coding **index.css**

```css
body{
    background-color: darkgrey;
}
.form-inline .form-control{
    width: 200px;
}
```

I want to change the search box size in width but when I am loading my web page it does not make any effect in search box size by loading external CSS file.

Comment: `this is not a duplicate question and should not be declared as duplicate question` - The community will judge that. What other questions have you looked in? Does clearing your cache / hard reloading help? Does the console show any errors?

Comment: 1 st check your path is correct. then refresh your page properly (by doing cnrtl+f5)

Comment: Open Chrome developer tools, select `.form-control` element, switch to `Computed` tab, find `width` property, and check if it has your value and if it is not overriden

Comment: "I think it's not loading in my web page" — You *think*? Why not gather some evidence. Open your browser's developer tools. Open the network tab. Reload the page. Look for the request for the stylesheet. See what response it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your path is wrong.

Try to put your css files in a same directory and correct your syntaxe :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

Reload your page.

If it works, it's certainly because you are using a relative path `css/index.css.` 
For your browser it's like you want to refer `mywebsite.com/css/index.css`. Add './' before `css/index.css`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
```